# Activity is too slow

Tags: android

I have an `Activity` which lets the users to choose a country. I use a custom view to show the countries (`TwoLevelListView`). Indeed, I have extended the `LinearLayout` to show the countries. Each country is depicted by a custom view (a Linear layout), under which I add a separator. I have two kind of separators which are visible in the following picture. I get the countries from a source which is a `TreeMap<String, LinkedList<String>>`. The problem is that the `Activity` is too slow- it takes around **0.6** seconds to load. I want to know where is the problem. I thought maybe I am inflating too many items, but if that is the case, how the applications like Viber or Telegram load too many views so fast?

[image]

and this the code if it helps:

```
public class TwoLevelListView extends LinearLayout
{

    private final Context context;
    //region private fields
    private TreeMap<String, ArrayList<String>> source;
    private View view;
    private LinearLayout bodyLl;
    private String sender;
    private Activity activity;
    //endregion

    public TwoLevelListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        doInflate(context);
    }

    private void doInflate(Context context)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comp_twolevellistview, this);
        setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate()
    {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        bodyLl = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.bodyLl);

    }

    private void addViews()
    {
        Iterator iterator = source.entrySet().iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext())
        {
            Map.Entry parent = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
            String parentStr = (String)parent.getKey();

            List<String> children = (List<String>) parent.getValue();
            addFirstChildView(parentStr, children.get(0), 0);

            for (int i = 1; i < children.size(); i++)
            {
                addChildSeparator();
                addChildView(parentStr, children.get(i), i);

            }
            addGroupSeparator();
        }
    }


    private void addFirstChildView(final String parent, final String child, final int childIdx)
    {
        ParentRow parentRow = new ParentRow(context);
        parentRow.setTexts(parent, child);
        parentRow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("sender", sender);
                intent.putExtra("parent", parent);
                intent.putExtra("child", child);
                intent.putExtra("childIdx", childIdx);
                activity.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
                activity.finish();
            }
        });
        bodyLl.addView(parentRow);
    }


    private void addChildView(final String parent, final String child, final int childIdx)
    {
        ChildRow childRow = new ChildRow(context);
        childRow.setChildText(child);
        childRow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("sender", sender);
                intent.putExtra("parent", parent);
                intent.putExtra("child", child);
                intent.putExtra("childIdx", childIdx);
                activity.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
                activity.finish();
            }
        });
        bodyLl.addView(childRow);
    }

    private void addChildSeparator()
    {
        ChildSeparator childSeparator = new ChildSeparator(context);
        bodyLl.addView(childSeparator);
    }
    private void addGroupSeparator()
    {
        GroupSeparator groupSeparator = new GroupSeparator(context);
        bodyLl.addView(groupSeparator);
    }

    public void setSource(TreeMap<String, ArrayList<String>> source)
    {
        this.source = source;
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        addViews();
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Logi("ui: " +  (endTime-startTime));
    }

    public void setSender(String sender) {
        this.sender = sender;
    }

    public void setActivity(Activity activity)
    {
        this.activity = activity;
    }
}


class ParentRow extends LinearLayout
{

    //region private fields
    private TextView childTV;
    private TextView parentTV;
    //endregion

    public ParentRow(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        doInflate(context);
    }

    private void doInflate(Context context)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comp_twolevellistview_parentrow, this);
        childTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.childTV);
        parentTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.parentTV);
    }

    public void setTexts(String parentTxt, String childTxt)
    {
        parentTV.setText(parentTxt);
        childTV.setText(childTxt);
    }

}


class ChildRow extends LinearLayout
{

    //region private fields
    TextView childTV;
    //endregion

    public ChildRow(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        doInflate(context);
    }

    private void doInflate(Context context)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comp_twolevellistview_childrow, this);
        childTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.childTV);
    }
    public void setChildText(String childTxt)
    {
        childTV.setText(childTxt);
    }
}


class ChildSeparator extends LinearLayout
{
    public ChildSeparator(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        doInflate(context);
    }

    private void doInflate(Context context)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comp_twolevellistview_separator, this);

    }
}

class GroupSeparator extends LinearLayout
{
    public GroupSeparator(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        doInflate(context);
    }

    private void doInflate(Context context)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comp_twolevellistview_groupseparator, this);

    }
}
```

Comment: how many entries do you have?

Comment: Hey, read about something called ViewHolder pattern. It's really easy to implement it. It looks like you are trying to inflate to many views (which is not really an efficient solutions).

Comment: @Blackbelt I have 197 (compound) views for the countries and 197 separators.

Comment: @scana Thanks. Indeed, I was looking for something like this. The name sounds promising, let's give it a try.

Comment: ViewHolder is not a magic wand... It will not help... What will help is AdaperView which is reusing the views... of course with right Adapter implementation(which may contain ViewHolder but it's only help with multiple findViewById calls)....

Comment: @Selvin I thought `AdapterView` can be used (effectively) with views like `ExpandableListView`, `GridView`, etc., and not in my case.

Comment: Your are wrong...  GridView is AdaperView... And in your case ListView(which is AdaperView, too)is a perfect solution

Comment: @Selvin Ok,Thank you. Although I didn't get how an AdapterView can help (increasing the speed), I will read about it and try to use it.

Comment: Might want to clean up title, the title is very ambiguous, but yes, ViewHolder can help a lot, but it takes a lot of work to get 'butter smooth' custom views (which I haven't worked on personally, but helped someone do)

Comment: @mawalker Perhaps. You can edit it, if you think so. Btw, I'm trying to use ViewHolder. Thanks.

Comment: Use RecyclerView, its handles a lot of optimizations internally.